# Getting ® as ? when reading from Struts 2 JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, encoding, struts2

I have a JSP page where when I enter the value "®" inside the `<s:textarea>` and then when I sysout in action class its printing "?".

Even replacing code cant detect it as "?", ie

say i entered "XYZ ®" inside `<s:textarea>`

In action class sysout its printing "XYZ ?".

Now, if am using

```
value = value.replace("?", "QQQQQ");
```

Its not replacing.

But if i am giving "XYZ ?" in `<s:textarea>` then the replace code is working.

My requirement is that from `<s:textarea>` the content containing "®" should be accessible in Java action class as a string variable and should display the same in another JSP page.

Right now its printing "®" as "?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it is because character is not recognized by encoding. To fix this you will need to change encoding to `UTF-8` to make this work. Please refer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12220483/how-to-change-charset-in-struts2-to-utf-8)

Comment: when i changed the encoding to UTF-8, its working now.. thanks.. :)

Answer (score 0):

The character should be escaped like `&reg;`.

You should always remember writing the HTML source code plainly in ASCII, instead of writing symbols, always write their ASCII equivalents.