# Error while passing email in request url path in struts 2

Tags: java, struts2, struts

I want to pass email in my request url path like

`http://myurl/user@email.com/`

Currently, this is my `struts.xml` :

```
<action name="{param1}/{param2}/" class="myActionClass">  
<result name="success">MyView.jsp</result>  
</action>
```

When I send a request (like the above url), I get an struts error saying :

`There is no Action mapped for action name index. - [unknown location]`

I figured out that the problem here is the usage of '@' character in the url path. How do I make my url work ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change charset in struts2 to utf-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12220483/how-to-change-charset-in-struts2-to-utf-8)

Comment: invalid characters should be urlencoded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should see something like the following in the logs

> user@email.com did not match allowed action names [a-zA-Z0-9._!/-]* -
>   default action index will be used!".

That means that `@` isn't allowed in action names and default action, which is by default is "index" will be used instead.
You can change allowed action names pattern with `struts.allowed.action.names` constant and default action name with `struts.default.action.name`.

Comment: Thank you. This solved my problem. Currently i'm sending the url as http://myurl/user@email.com/ and if i remove the '/' it gives me a 404 not found error. Is there anyway I can make the url work without the '/' ?

Comment: @user5739878, please post as a new question with `struts2` tag then more people have you in monitor.